# How to unset a variable in Twig

Tags: twig

So I'm working with conditional rendering in a component reused at multiple place.

I have a twig variable `my_var` set as **'something'**.

I want to unset it in my template.

Something like `{% unset my_var %}` the way this condition `{% if not my_var %}` would be fullfill.

I've tried to set it to `false` or `null` but this is not working anytips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working here:

```
{% set my_var = false %}
{% if not my_var %}
    not true
{% else %}
    true
{% endif %}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/3b1kol)

Comment: You just manage to show me the problem wasn't comming from there. Ty :)